# Change the Ankh Subversion / SVN URL folder path in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I have a bunch of projects in my SVN Repo like so:

```
/Projects/Alpha
/Projects/Beta
/Projects/Gamma
/Projects/Delta
```

On my local machine, the repo maps to

`c:\Projects`

I don't want to checkout all the Repo's projects to my local machine. So, I have used Repo Browser to just checkout the projects I want. Therefore on my local machine I have got:

```
c:\Projects\Alpha
c:\Projects\Beta
```

This is fine until I open up the `Beta` project in Visual Studio, which has Ankh installed. When the solution opens, the `Pending Changes` window shows the following repo URL:

`https://myrepo.local/svn/Projects`

To me, the URL is wrong. As it is, when I click the `Update` button in `Pending Changes`, it starts to update all the files in `Projects` - when I only want to update the files for `Beta`. Therefore I think the URL should really be

`https://myrepo.local/svn/Projects/Beta`

However when I change the URL to that, it seems to want to do a SVN Switch, which doesn't seem right. It thinks I want to associate the Path `C:\Projects` with `https://myrepo.local/svn/Projects/Beta`, which is incorrect.

So can anyone tell me how to sort this out, and why the `Beta` project thinks its repo URL is `https://myrepo.local/svn/Projects` in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's been a while, nobody answered my question, and I forgot about it.

Then today I faced the same problem on a different project, googled the issue and the only person who seems to share my pain is...... me, from 8 months ago.

However this time I've solved it!!

The fix is, in Visual Studio (using 2013 here), with your solution open, go to `File / Subversion / Change Source Control` and browse to the correct `SCC Binding Path` for your solution folder. Click `Connect` and it fixed the issue.